# What would happen SHA-256 collision were to be found?

Tags: hash, security

As far as I and this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithms#cite_note-2) page know, there are no collisions (2 inputs with the same output) found in SHA-256 (yet).
what would happen if a collision were to be found,

**1. would it be easier to find more collisions? (based on the first collision found)**

**2. is a single collision found a major security risk as the only thing an attacker can do is switch between those inputs? (or is there a way to reduce any different inputs to the collision found input)**

**3. would (and should) it stopped being used?**

Answer (score 1):

If given some data we could at will create different data with the same SHA that would be a bad problem. Dump SHA.

If we could at will create two sets of data with the same SHA, someone will figure out a way to turn that into a fatal problem.

If someone uses a supercomputer to create *one* collision at a cost that would be outside my reach, I think that wouldn’t be a problem.

Comment: Afaik, SHA-256 uses the Merkle–Damgård transform, so if we have *one* collision pair $x,y$ (i.e., $H(x) = H(y)$  for $x\neq y$) we can use the length extension attack to turn it into as many collision pairs as we desire by considering $xz$ and $yz'$ for suitable (easy to find) suffixes $z$ and $z'$.

Comment: @kelalaka: but $x$ and $y$ migh have different lengths, which would require a different start of the suffix (because it needs to match the Merkle–Damgård padding). Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Steven I've somehow, considered they have the same size, my shame. Deleted the comment. if sizes are different than the padding is different and even the length extension attack can fail to find collision as long as the padding doesn't make the size same.